# R FFTrees Error Possibly Due to Missingness

Tags: r

I'm receiving an error when trying to build a model in FFTrees. I believe this is due to missingness.

Minimal reprexes:

```
library(FFTrees)

heartdisease2 <- heartdisease

heart.fft <- FFTrees(formula = diagnosis ~., 
                 data = heartdisease2)
```

The above works fine. However, when I simulate missingness in the predictor columns, the model fails:

```
for(i in 2:ncol(heartdisease2)){
  missingrows <- sample(1:nrow(heartdisease2), .2*nrow(heartdisease2))
  heartdisease2[missingrows,i] <- NA
}


heart.fft <- FFTrees(formula = diagnosis ~., 
                 data = heartdisease2)
```

with following error:

```
>Error in if (is.na(best.result.index)) { : argument is of length zero
>In addition: Warning message:
>In max(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,  :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

According to the package, the latest version of FFTrees should be able to deal with missingness. Is anyone else experiencing this error?

Answer (score 0):

I am reading the package updates here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FFTrees/readme/README.html

I don't see any mention of the latest version handling NAs. Could you possibly point me towards where you saw this?

Comment: I saw it referenced in this blog post: https://ndphillips.github.io/blog/simplicity-matters-3-updates-to-the-fftrees-universe/#fftrees-v1.3.3. It's also referenced in the issues section on the Github repo: https://github.com/ndphillips/FFTrees/issues/28